# Entityframework 6 : How to map custom types to SQL tables

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-6, mapping

I searched for topic on this subjects but none of them answered my question.

Here is my problem :

I'm working with EF 6 Base-first. I need to map custom entities I created myself with SQL tables.
Let's say I've a SQL table Client like this :

```sql
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
id int primary key,
info1 varchar,
info2 varchar,
info3 varchar,
info4 varchar,
info5 varchar);
```

and a C# class Client as

```cs
public class Client{
 private int id {get; set;}
 private string info2 {get; set;}
 private string info5 {get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to be able to manipulate this Client class in a DbContext as I would manipulate an auto-generated EDMX class. By doing so i would only manipulate the fields my application needs.
My goal is to be able to use it like that

```cs
using(var ctxt = new CustomDbContext())
{
     ctxt.Entry(client).State = client.id == 0? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

so I could insert/update entry into my Client table, without crushing data from info1, info3 and info4 that I do not use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As class with only private properties? Anyway, if you don't map the other properties you're OK, i.e. remove them from the class in the designer. However this is only possible if the unmapped columns are nullable, otherwise you won't ever be able to insert data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you should create some class that inherits from `DbContext` to set up your context, and then you will create a virtual property on that class like with `DbSet<T> MyProperty {get;set;}`

So something probably like:

```
public class YourEntity : DbContext
{
    //Configuration stuff for your entity
    ...

    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is the right way. I used this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-6-code-first-approach/. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, then I'd use DbEntityEntry.
I hope this ressource will help you with how it actually works.

http://kerryritter.com/updating-or-replacing-entities-in-entity-framework-6/

Have fun

Comment: Hello, this could solve the problem but I decided to use another approach : table splitting using this : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-6-code-first-approach/